# how to get values of check box in array send to other page using javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
Cricket<input name="hobbies[]" type="checkbox" value="cricket"  checked="checked" /> 
    &nbsp; 
    books Reading <input type="checkbox" value="books_reading" name="hobbies[]"  />
    &nbsp; 
    Football <input type="checkbox" value="Football" name="hobbies[]"  />
    
    &nbsp; 
    Swiming <input type="checkbox" value="Swiming" name="hobbies[]"  />
```

Cricket 
      
    books Reading 
      
    Football

```
&nbsp; 
Swiming <input type="checkbox" value="Swimming" name="hobbies[]"  />
```

i want to get the values of check box in array using java script and want to send it to another page for further process can some help me in this process

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: Are you using a particular MVC framework? For reference: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Comment: Send to another page means ? On what action do you want to send the values ? some button somewhere that clicks and a form submits. Im trying to understand what exactly the problem is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select an array of the checked checkbox, loop through it. Then get its values.

```
var arr = [];
var checkboxes = $('input:checked');
    checkboxes.each(function(index, value){
    arr.push($(value).val());
});
```